# How to script editor to clear cells but keep formula in certain cells

Tags: google-apps-script-editor

Is there a way to keep formulas in certain cells when I have a clear cell script. At the moment it clears everything and removes my formula.

Cells with formulas are - 'H2' & 'K2'

```
function reset() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet.getRange("F3:K8").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: H2 and K2 should not be getting cleared when the range is F3:K8.

Comment: Sorry supposed to be H3 & K3

Answer (score 0):

Clearing your content will always clear the formula in a cell. A cell has a text/number literal or a formula in it. There's not a function that will clear one and not the other.

But, you can check to see if a cell contains a formula, and if so, don't clear the content for it. That will functionally do what you want.

```
function reset() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = sheet.getRange('F3:K8');
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      if (range.getCell(i,j).getFormula());
      {
        range.getCell(i,j).clearContent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```